# how to discernin between "cause" and " reason"?

Tags: vocabulary, word-difference

I know somehow the word reason deals with **justification**
**explanation**, and **cause**. In other words, although the word *reason*, considering the text, could mean each of the bold ones,  I am wondering what is the difference between A and B?

A."the main reasons for immigration"

B. "the main causes for immigration"

Any comment would greatly be appreciated

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in meaing.  Cause can be used as a countable/uncountable noun to mean reasons/reason for something. However, it's more common to use it as a non-count .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reason is a thought that is why someone does something. A cause is something that makes something else happen. Reason should explain something, cause might not, it might just be due to something else without an explanation.

They're usually treated the same, though.

Comment: I appreciate your answer even though I am not the OP.
But please look at this example sentence from a dictionary. ***When the war ended, people finally had cause to rejoice.*** Here, how can I apply your explanation? Is it equivalent to ***When the war ended, people finally had reason to rejoice***?

Answer (score 0):

Cause : (noun) 
( 1) That which produces an effect, thing, event, person, etc…make something happen
What was the cause of the fire? 
Smoking is one of the causes of heart disease.

( 2) Aim, principle or movement that is strongly defended or supported
His life was devoted to the cause of justice. 
Cause : (verb) 
( 1) Make happen
Be a cause of something
Smoking can cause lung cancer. 
She is always causing trouble for people. 
The cold weather caused the plants to die. 
Reason : (noun) 
( 1) Motive or justification for something
Give me the reason for your going. 
He has adequate reason for doing so.

( 2) Power of the mind to think, understand, form opinion, etc…
Only man has reason.

( 3) What is right or practical or possible
Common sense
Judgment
There is a good deal of reason in what you say.

( 4) CAUSE of something is what makes something happen. 
The police are investigating the cause of the explosion.

( 5) REASON for something has a wider use. It can be the explanation that people give for why something is done.

( 6) What was the reason for his resignation?

She did not give any reason for leaving.